Is it safe to call copy_from_user with kernel space address after set_fs(KERNEL_DS)?
I am developing a linux kernel module in kernel-4.9.168, for some reason, I want to call another module(vfio)'s file ops. The vfio module provide some file ops such as write, it basically like this:
static ssize_t do_io_rw(struct vfio_pci_device *vdev, bool test_mem,
            void __iomem *io, char __user *buf,
            loff_t off, size_t count, size_t x_start,
            size_t x_end, bool iswrite)
{
    ssize_t done = 0;
    int ret;

    while (count) {
        size_t fillable, filled;

        if (off < x_start)
            fillable = min(count, (size_t)(x_start - off));
        else if (off >= x_end)
            fillable = count;
        else
            fillable = 0;

        if (fillable >= 4 && !(off % 4)) {
            u32 val;

            if (iswrite) {
                if (copy_from_user(&val, buf, 4))
                    return -EFAULT;

                ret = vfio_pci_iowrite32(vdev, test_mem,
                             val, io + off);
                if (ret)
                    return ret;
}

I know copy_from_user will check if address is userspace by compare addr_limit with buf argument, so in my own module, I use kernel_write to bypass userspace check like this:
static int my_module_code(struct file *file, struct vhost_virtqueue *vvq)
{
    loff_t pos = yyy;
    unsigned int *idx = &vvq->idx;


    return __kernel_write(file, (char *)idx, 2, &pos);
}

kernel_write will set_fs(KERNEL_DS) before calling file->ops->write, it work fine but I feel uncomfortable with my code, after all the copy_from_user is named with user.
So is my code safe? or there is a better way to handle this?

Yes, it perfectly possible, yet it's preferable if you find a different way to achieve your goals, as this method is error prone

Yes, even though it looks weird it should be fine. The reason why __kernel_write() does set_fs(KERNEL_DS) is exactly because it needs to call functions that want __user addresses while actually passing kernel addresses. It does:
old_fs = get_fs();
set_fs(get_ds());
ret = __vfs_write(file, (__force const char __user *)buf, count, pos);
set_fs(old_fs);

Where __vfs_write requires a __user buffer, since it's going to directly call file->f_ops->write().
